# Crear gráfico a partir de tabla con valores duplicados

Tags: excel

Tengo una tabla de 3 columnas.
Sector, Compras, Inversion.

En la tabla por motivos de funcionamiento hay varias filas que comparten sector.
Ej:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creé un grafico el cual esta enlazado a esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El gráfico como ven me toma 2 veces IT y 2 veces Administracion
Lo que quiero hacer es que tome 1 única vez cada sector y que represente en el gráfico la suma de la columna inversión para cada sector. Teniendo así un gráfico que indique que porcentaje de la inversión fue a cada sector.

Comment: Prueba con una tabla dinámica que agrupe por sector y forma tu gráfico a partir de esa tabla dinámica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo te decía, si insertas una tabla dinámica en base a tu tabla y generas el gráfico tomando los valores de la tabla dinámica tendrás lo que que buscas:

[image: Grafico + Tabla Dinámica]